# How can I overwrite in a Spark DataFrame null entries with other valid entries from the same dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a Spark DataFrame with data like this

```
|  id |  value1 |value2  |
------------------------
|  1  |  null   |    1   |
|  1  |   2     |  null  |
```

And want to transform it

into

```
|  id |  value1 |value2 |
-----------------------
|  1  |    2    |   1   |
```

That is, I need to get the rows with the same id and merge their values in a single row.

Could you explain me what is the most scalable way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupBy(“id”).agg(collect_set(“value1”).alias(“value1”),collect_set(“value2”).alias(“value2”))
```

//more elegant way of doing for dynamic columns

```
df.groupBy(“id”).agg(df.columns.tail.map((_ -> “collect_set”)).toMap).show
```

//1.5

```
Val df1=df.rdd.map(i=>(i(0).toString,i(1).toString)).groupByKey.mapValues(_.toSet.toList.filter(_!=“null”)).toDF()
Val df2 = df.rdd.map(i=>(i(0).toString,i(2).toString)).groupByKey.mapValues(_.toSet.toList.filter(_!=“null”)).toDF()
df1.join(df2,df1(“_1”) === df2(“_1”),”inner”).drop(df2(“_1”)).show
```

Comment: Thank you. I still have one problem with the `collect_set` function. It is not being found. I found somewhere that `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` should fix that, but I'm still stuck there

Comment: It’s part of the above package you mentioned. Please share the error.

Comment: scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._                                               import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ scala> output.toDF().groupBy("_1").agg(collect_set("_2"))                              <console>:90: error: not found: value collect_set output.toDF().groupBy("_1").agg(collect_set("_2"))

Comment: Your spark version please. and please share the value for output.toDF

Comment: My spark version is 1.5.0-cdh5.5.1. The value of output.toDF() is org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string, _2: string, _3: string]

Comment: This api is available since 1.6. I updated the answer with respect to 1.5